# CDI - CODI - ViewAccessScoped on produces = Error 

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, cdi, codi

In a jsf page where i get data from a baking bean like that

```
<p:dataList value="#{userArtifacts}" var="art" itemType="artifact" type="inset">
```

i got a java.lang.StackOverflowError,

My backing bean look like that, i want to have a producer to cache data and maybe later override it ...

I just want to maintain the list during the ViewAccessScope

Btw it seem that if a change my Producer to SessionScope i have no problem

```
@Named
@ViewAccessScoped
public class FArtifacts  implements Serializable{

@PostConstruct
public void init()
{
    artifacts= getArtifactController().getArtifact(15);
    System.out.println("[INIT] Get All Art");

}

@Produces
@ViewAccessScoped
@Named("userArtifacts")
public List<Article> getMyArtifacts()
{

    System.out.println("[CUSTOM] Return all");
    return  artifacts;

}
```

the servlet exception is :

```
javax.servlet.ServletException
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:606)
    org.jboss.weld.servlet.ConversationPropagationFilter.doFilter(ConversationPropagationFilter.java:62)
```

the stack error that loop look like that :

```
org.jboss.weld.bean.AbstractReceiverBean.getReceiver(AbstractReceiverBean.java:77)
    org.jboss.weld.bean.AbstractProducerBean$AbstractProducer.produce(AbstractProducerBean.java:317)
    org.jboss.weld.bean.AbstractProducerBean.create(AbstractProducerBean.java:307)
    org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.core.impl.util.CodiUtils.createNewInstanceOfBean(CodiUtils.java:69)
    org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.jsf.impl.scope.conversation.AbstractConversationBeanEntry.createNewBeanInstance(AbstractConversationBeanEntry.java:139)
    org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.jsf.impl.scope.conversation.AbstractConversationBeanEntry.getBeanInstance(AbstractConversationBeanEntry.java:84)
    org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.jsf.impl.scope.conversation.DefaultConversation.getBean(DefaultConversation.java:163)
    org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.jsf.impl.scope.conversation.GroupedConversationContext.resolveBeanInstance(GroupedConversationContext.java:185)
    org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.core.impl.scope.conversation.AbstractGroupedConversationContext.resolve(AbstractGroupedConversationContext.java:114)
    org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.core.impl.scope.conversation.AbstractGroupedConversationContext.create(AbstractGroupedConversationContext.java:79)
    org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.core.impl.scope.conversation.ConversationContextAdapter.get(ConversationContextAdapter.java:81)
    org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:599)
    org.jboss.weld.bean.AbstractReceiverBean.getReceiver(AbstractReceiverBean.java:77)
    org.jboss.weld.bean.AbstractProducerBean$AbstractProducer.produce(AbstractProducerBean.java:317)
    org.jboss.weld.bean.AbstractProducerBean.create(AbstractProducerBean.java:307)
    org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.core.impl.util.CodiUtils.createNewInstanceOfBean(CodiUtils.java:69)
    org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.jsf.impl.scope.conversation.AbstractConversationBeanEntry.createNewBeanInstance(AbstractConversationBeanEntry.java:139)
    org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.jsf.impl.scope.conversation.AbstractConversationBeanEntry.getBeanInstance(AbstractConversationBeanEntry.java:84)
    org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.jsf.impl.scope.conversation.DefaultConversation.getBean(DefaultConversation.java:163)
    org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.jsf.impl.scope.conversation.GroupedConversationContext.resolveBeanInstance(GroupedConversationContext.java:185)
    org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.core.impl.scope.conversation.AbstractGroupedConversationContext.resolve(AbstractGroupedConversationContext.java:114)
    org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.core.impl.scope.conversation.AbstractGroupedConversationContext.create(AbstractGroupedConversationContext.java:79)
    org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.core.impl.scope.conversation.ConversationContextAdapter.get(ConversationContextAdapter.java:81)
    org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:599)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are old versions of PrimeFaces which cause issues with the Window-ID parameter. If you are using a new version, you should report the issue to the PrimeFaces team.

Comment: I use primesface 3.4.1 .. on JBOSS AS 7.1.3 (weld)

Comment: no problem if i change the producer to requested scope  '@Produces
@RequestedScoped
@Named("userArtifacts")
public List<Article> getMyArtifacts()
{

    System.out.println("[CUSTOM] Return all");
    return  artifacts;

}'

Comment: Is it the same with a simple producer (== no list)? Is it the same with #{myBean.myList} + MyBean is a @ViewAccessScoped and has a Getter-Method (getMyList)? Is it the same with a blank demo without PrimeFaces? How do you inject it?